# I'm was getting an error "Localhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" when trying to run Mailpit on my localhost environment with docker

Tags: docker, email, smtp

Yes I've gone through whole configuration process

```
docker pull axllent/mailpit
```

I've run the mailpit container using

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name mailpit axllent/mailpit
```

I've updated the .env file with smtp configs
But when I go to localhost:8080 I get ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error.

Answer (score 0):

On opening docker I noticed the container is running on a wrong port that is 8025 contrary to port 80 mapped in the command. So I stopped the container using command

`docker stop mailpit docker rm mailpit`

then updated the port using

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8025 --name mailpit axllent/mailpit
```